# Fractional Exponent Identity: Is the inside of a root necessarily calculated first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, exponentiation, radicals

I know $a^{b/c}=\sqrt[c]{a^b}$, but does $a^b$ have to be calculated first, or does $a^{b/c}=(\sqrt[c]a\,)^b$ also work? Thanks.

Comment: I assume you meant to put $b$, not $n$. If so, they are equivalent for $a\ge 0$. $a^{b/c} = (a^b)^{1/c} = (a^{1/c})^b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $a > 0$ is a real number, and taking
$$
a^{b/c} = \sqrt[c]{a^b}
$$
as the definition of the rational power. Let's raise the new expression $x = (\sqrt[c]{a}\,)^b$ to the power $c$ and apply exponent properties:
\begin{align}
x^c &= \bigl((\sqrt[c]{a}\,)^b\bigr)^c \\ 
&= (\sqrt[c]{a}\,)^{bc} \\ 
&= (\sqrt[c]{a}\,)^{cb} \\ 
&= \bigl((\sqrt[c]{a}\,)^c\bigr)^b \\
&= a^b
\end{align}
Thus, $x$ is the $c$-root of $a^b$, which was your original definition for $a^{b/c}$, hence they are all the same number.

**Note:** This all becomes a bit more complicated if you allow $a$ to be a negative real number or non-real complex number or any other type of number where raising to a power is not a *one-to-one* operation. In that case, it's not even clear how to define the root since there's potentially more than one.